# Parsing specific pattern with optional subgroups

Tags: regex

I have an input string according to the following pattern:

```
'A)any string B) any other string C) third different string D)last free string'
```

where any of the subgroups is optional, e.g. both are proper inputs:

```
'A)any string D)last free string'

'D)last free string'
```

Is there a way to write a regexp that will match subexpressions such way:

```
'A)any string'

'B) any other string'

'C) third different string' 

'D)last free string'
```

I tried greedy:

```
(A\).*)?(B\).*)?(C\).*)?(D\).*)?
```

and also lazy:

```
(A\).*?)?(B\).*?)?(C\).*?)?(D\).*?)?
```

but neither works correctly.

Can this be done with regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(A\).*?(?=B\)|C\)|D\)))?(B\).*?(?=C\)|D\)))?(C\).*?(?=D\)))?((A\)|B\)|C\)|D\)).*)?
```

as pattern. In detail its:

```
(A\).*?(?=B\)|C\)|D\)))?
```

- `(...)?` as you already used the whole block is optional
- `A\)`    the block has to start with `A)`
- `.*?`    any string, but ungreedy regarding the next statement
- `(?=B\)|C\)|D\))` lookahead for either `B)`, `C)` or `D)`. In combination of the ungreedy statement before this makes the whole expression stopping as soon as one of the `X)` is found

Next block:

```
(B\).*?(?=C\)|D\)))?
```

- `(...)?` same as above
- `B\)`    the block has to start with `B)`
- `.*?`    same as above
- `(?=C\)|D\))` same as above, but only lookahead for `C)` or `D)`

Next block:

```
(C\).*?(?=D\)))?
```

- `(...)?` same as above
- `C\)`    the block has to start with `C)`
- `.*?`    same as above
- `(?=C\)|D\))` same as above, but only lookahead for `D)`

Next block:

```
((A\)|B\)|C\)|D\)).*)?
```

- `(...)?` same as above
- `(A\)|B\)|C\)|D\))`    the block has to start with either `A)`, `B)`, `C)` or `D)`
- `.*` any string, but greedy. Otherwise would be just an empty string

This last block is necessary to match the single patterns (including `D)` only) or the ones not ending with a `D)` block

Comment: This solution has worked. The only problem is that depending on the input string to retrieve the last submatch one must refer either to  "regular" pattern or to the submatch in "((A\)|B\)|C\)|D\)).*)?" block. This complicates the usage a little, but in the end it all works. Thx, SBH.